# How to show html in rails options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, drop-down-menu

I used rails `options_from_collection_for_select` for select.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@tenants, :id, :tenant_text_value, current_tenant.try(:id))

def tenant_text_value
  "<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>".html_safe
end
```

I want `<option value="215"><a href='http://www.google.com'>google</option>` and when I click `a` I go to Google.

However, I just get `<option value="215">Google</option>`.

If I use `"<a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a>".to_s`, I get `<option value="215"><a href='http://www.google.com'>google</a></option>`. Just a text, not a link.

What should I do ?

Comment: I think you need jquery or the :onchange option of select tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag '<some_id>', options_from_collection_for_select(@tenants, :id, :tenant_text_value, current_tenant.try(:id)),:onchange => "window.location.href(this.value);" %>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag '<some_id>', options_from_collection_for_select(@tenants, :id, :tenant_text_value, current_tenant.try(:id)) %>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#team_id').bind('change', function () {
         var url = $(this).val()
          if (url) {
              window.location.href(url);
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do and you have a flawed on what you want to do.

I think that you want to do is when someone selects something to go to a page

Expected output

```
<select id="abc">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Bing</option>
</select>

$("#abc").change(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Rails

```
<%= 
  select_tag "abc", 
  options_from_collection_for_select(@tenants, @tenant.url, @tenant.name", @tenant.id) 
%>
```

I hope that this helps you out

Happy Hacking

Comment: Missed it by that much...Was busy adding comment to question instead... :D

Comment: Thank, but I need get tenant_id from option value. So I should use jQuery to finish.